# Form submits but by passing the form validation when button.click is used

Tags: jquery, html

I am using form validation  plugin as well as html5 attribute=recquired with input type=button or submit and fancybox.when button is clicked ,both validation proceedures work(notification of empty inputs appeare),but instead of this  notification ,form is submitted.

If I dont use button.click function but use simple submit.then validation works perfectly

**plugin**==http://validatious.org/

javascript function

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#send').click(function() {

    $(this).attr("value", 'Applying...');


    var id = getParam('ID');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"send.php",



        data:{option:'catapply', tittle:$('#tittle').val(), aud:aud, con:con, adv:adv, mid:$('#mid').val(), aud2:aud, cid:$('#cid').val(), scid:$('#scname option[selected="saa"]').val(), gtt:$('input[name=gt]:radio:checked').val(), sr:$(":input").serialize() + '&aud=' + aud},

        success:function(jd) {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut("fast", function() {
                $(this).before("<strong>Success! Your form has been submitted, thanks :)</strong>");
                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
            });
        }
    });
  });
 });
```

AND Html is here

```
      <form id="form2" class="validate" style="display: none" >

        <input  type='button'  value='Apply' id="send" class="sendaf validate_any"                              name="jobforming"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: try using `<input  type='button'` and use the submit function. PD: You have a problem with commas and white spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EITHER have a type="button" and not a type="submit" OR what I vastly prefer, run on form submit instead of on click. the preventDefault (or return false at the end of the function) will stop the normal form submission UNLESS there is a syntax error in the code! For example what is aud and con?

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#form2").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop normal submission

    $('#send').attr("value", 'Applying...');

    var id = getParam('ID');
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:"send.php",
      data:{option:'catapply', tittle:$('#tittle').val(), aud:aud, con:con, adv:adv, mid:$('#mid').val(), aud2:aud, cid:$('#cid').val(), scid:$('#scname option[selected="saa"]').val(), gtt:$('input[name=gt]:radio:checked').val(), sr:$(":input").serialize() + '&aud=' + aud},

      success:function(jd) {
        $('#' + id).fadeOut("fast", function() {
          $(this).before("<strong>Success! Your form has been submitted, thanks :)</strong>");
          setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: He should use a submit button, preventing submission.

Comment: @rayfranco now form html5 attribute works,but plugin function is bypasse

Comment: @CutyPie Please see updated comments and have a look in the console for errors

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work with your validation plugin. Even if *mplungjan* answer is, in my opinion, a better solution in most cases (listening on submit event instead of listening on the submit button click).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').click(function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       $(this).attr("value", 'Applying...');

       var id = getParam('ID');

       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:"send.php",
           data:{option:'catapply', tittle:$('#tittle').val(), aud:aud, con:con, adv:adv, mid:$('#mid').val(), aud2:aud, cid:$('#cid').val(), scid:$('#scname option[selected="saa"]').val(), gtt:$('input[name=gt]:radio:checked').val(), sr:$(":input").serialize() + '&aud=' + aud},
           success:function(jd) {
               $('#' + id).fadeOut("fast", function() {
                   $(this).before("<strong>Success! Your form has been submitted, thanks :)</strong>");
                   setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
               });
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: still bypassing the plugin validation

Comment: It seems that Validatious have no solid API to deal our own submit event. Have you tought of an alternative that will deal good with ajax form submission ?

Comment: @CutyPie For example, the library validate.js seems to be more "low level" but allow you to make your own callback after the plugin validation. You could add your $.ajax in there